# Where can I find a reference guide of names of macos keys?

Tags: reference, applescript

I have been beating my head against this for an hour or so.

I have decided I will force myself to learn enough applescript to do a simple text macro.

All I want to do is

```
down arrow
command + right arrow
,
function + backspace
command + right arrow
,
function + backspace
command + right arrow
,
function + backspace
command + right arrow
,
function + backspace
```

but I can find nowhere a list of arguments to keystroke that will perform the above.

Comment: Look at the `keystroke` and `key code` _commands_ in the System Events AppleScript dictionary in the Library in Script Editor. Google, _AppleScript key codes_.

Comment: I did. But there is no list of names of keys, nor a list of key codes.

Comment: The `keystroke` and `key code` _commands_ in the System Events dictionary: **key code** v : cause the target process to behave as if key codes were entered **key code** integer : The key code(s) to be sent. May be a list. [**using** command down/‌control down/‌option down/‌shift down] : modifiers with which the key codes are to be entered | **keystroke** v : cause the target process to behave as if keystrokes were entered **keystroke** text : The keystrokes to be sent. [**using** command down/‌control down/‌option down/‌shift down] : modifiers with which the keystrokes are to be entered

Comment: Top Google hit for _AppleScript key codes_: [Complete list of AppleScript key codes - eastman reference](https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes/) So when you say "But there is no list of names of keys, nor a list of key codes." I just have to say **BS** to that!

Comment: @user3439894: Thank you for the useful link. I posted a similar link in my answer below. But please note, when I wrote "But there is no list..." I was referring to the entries in the AppleScript System Events dictionary, not the Web as a whole. The System Events dictionary does not refer to an exhaustive list of **keystroke** and **key code** arguments. IMO it is not unreasonable to expect a complete reference guide to these values to be easily found in the system help, or on apple.com. So I call BS on your BS call.

Comment: The AppleScript dictionaries for the various applications are quite sparse and do not even provide much of an explanation how to use the info contained or even an example, so IMO it's unreasonable to expect a list of key codes and as to a list of keystrokes, well you do have the keyboard right in front of you so that list is not necessary to be included. A Google search for _AppleScript key codes_ gets one that information quickly and easily, it not hard nor is it rocket science!

Comment: I think this list is more helpful and perhaps more inclusive: http://macbiblioblog.blogspot.com/2014/12/key-codes-for-function-and-special-keys.html

Comment: @jweaks, That is another of the top hits when searching Google for, _AppleScript key codes_, which Magic Thighs could have easily found had he actually tried searching.

Answer (score -1):

By beating my head some more against the wall I managed to find an answer by using the genetic programming approach (try various permutations, and add and delete text).

It looks like key code 117 (backspace) behaves like fn+backspace.

So I never did find a reference list.

```
# http://web.archive.org/web/20100501161453/http://www.classicteck.com/rbarticles/mackeyboard.php
tell application "BBEdit"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 125
        key code 124 using {command down}
        keystroke ","
        key code 117
        key code 124 using {command down}
        keystroke ","
        key code 117
        key code 124 using {command down}
        keystroke ","
        key code 117
        key code 124 using {command down}
    end tell
end tell
```